# Toggle appending element to different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to move `.item` from `.region1` to `.region2` when the anchor tag is clicked, and also move it back to `.region1` when it is clicked again? So pretty much the behavior of a toggle ?

```
  <a href="#" class="btn">Click</div>
  <div class="region1">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="region2"></div>
```

Comment: Yep it is possible.Just add a click event to the anchor tag and add 'item' class to the respective div elements based on the condition check of hasClass().

Answer (score 0):

Just build the toggle like function by yourself. Check if the element is is there then use `appendTo` to move the element.

```js
$('a.btn').click(function() {
  if ($('.region1 > .item').length) {
    $('.region1 > .item').appendTo('.region2');
  }
  else {
    $('.region2 > .item').appendTo('.region1');
  }
});
```

```css
.region1 { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red; }
.region2 { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn">Click</a>
<div class="region1">
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
<div class="region2"></div>
```

If there is only one `.item` in the whole page, you could make it shorter:

```js
$('a.btn').click(function() {
  $('.item').appendTo($('.region1 > .item').length ? '.region2' : '.region1');
});
```

```css
.region1 { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red; }
.region2 { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn">Click</a>
<div class="region1">
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
<div class="region2"></div>
```

Or without jQuery:

```js
document.querySelector('a.btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (item = document.querySelector('.region1 > .item')) {
    document.querySelector('.region2').append(item);
  } else if (item = document.querySelector('.region2 > .item')) {
    document.querySelector('.region1').append(item);
  }
});
```

```css
.region1 { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red; }
.region2 { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn">Click</a>
<div class="region1">
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
<div class="region2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make use of `append()` to achieve the toggle effect:

```js
function toggleItem(){
  var $item = $('.region1').find('.item');
  if($item.length !== 0){
    $('.region2').append($item);
  } else {
    $item = $('.region2').find('.item');
    $('.region1').append($item);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn" onclick='toggleItem()'>Click</a>
<div class="region1">Inside region 1
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
<div class="region2">Inside region 2</div>
```

Comment: Why would you use `find` and jQuery objects every time again? Just unnecessary function calls ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in vanilla JavaScript:

```js
var item = document.querySelector('.item');
var region1 = document.querySelector('.region1');
var region2 = document.querySelector('.region2');

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (region1.contains(item)) {
    region2.appendChild(item);
  } else if (region2.contains(item)) {
    region1.appendChild(item);
  }
});
```

```css
.region1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.region2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Click</a>
<div class="region1">
  <div class="item">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="region2"></div>
```

**Note:**

Because there's probably more than just one single `a` tag in your page, you should not use `...querySelector('a')...` like this. To ensure the proper `a` tag gets selected, you should make it unique, e. g. by adding an id to it. If you decide to use the way with the id, replace the your `querySelector('a')` with `querySelector('#yourid')`.

---

**And thank you** to [eisbehr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6498658/eisbehr) for helping me to cut down the script in an very effective way.

Comment: You could do this much, much smaller. Way to much code.

Comment: Oh, and your event will be triggered for every `a` tag on the page! ;)

Comment: @eisbehr While I agree with you about your first comment, I have to disagree about your second one. `querySelector` returns only the first match. According to OPs code, my example is fine.

Comment: Well, you should not think just about the example of the OP, but as in a webpage context. So there is a very high chance that there is more than one anchor inside his page. ;) But it's yours ...

Comment: @eisbehr That's another good point. I'll edity my answer by adding that OP should be aware of that.

Comment: I don't want to bother you, just to give you hints. Don't mind me if not wanted. But you could move the vars `item `, `region1` and `region2` outside of the event handler, because they will probably don't change, This would save the query over and over again. And as you have the vars already, you could use `contains()` instead of a `querySelector` every time. Like `if(region1.contains(item))`. And you don't need to use `removeChild`. You can just use `append` on another element, then the child will be moved to it, because an element can only be have a single parent node.

Comment: @eisbehr No, thank your for pointing it out! Your tips are greatly appreciated! I'm always happy to learn new stuff. :p